# How to format number to Serbian format using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I have number sent from form like this:

```
0641234567
064-123/4567
064/123-4567
3816412345678
```

And it needs to be like this:

```
+3816412345678
```

with +, without 0 and with max 14 characters including '+'.

How can i solve that using regex?

Comment: What have you tried? All results should produce the `+3816412345678` or just last example?

Comment: If you can solve something without regex - solve it without regex :)
You can try to use `str_replace` for removing not valid characters and all start characters except `64`, check length with `strlen` and then add prefix `+381`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is multiple replacement with basically three rules,

- replace `-` or `/` with empty string
- replace the zero in the beginning with `+381`
- Put a `+` in the beginning of number if the first number is any 1 to 9

Check this [PHP Demo](https://rextester.com/MHKLZR64129),

```
$arr = ['0641234567','064-123/4567','064/123-4567','3816412345678'];

foreach($arr as $s) {
    echo $s." --> ".preg_replace(['/^0/', '/^(?=[1-9])/', '/[-\/]/'], ['+381', '+', ''], $s)."\n";
}
```

Prints,

```
0641234567 --> +381641234567
064-123/4567 --> +381641234567
064/123-4567 --> +381641234567
3816412345678 --> +3816412345678
```

Let me know if any of your case goes uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

The data you showed may be incomplete, and there could be edge cases other than what we can see right.  Based on what we do see right now, your replacement can be implemented by replacing a leading `064` with `38164`, and then stripping all dashes and forward slashes.  Using `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "064-123/4567";
$output = preg_replace('/[\/-]/', '', preg_replace('/^064/', '38164', $input));
echo $input . "\n" . $output;

064-123/4567
381641234567
```